# How do I sort using Fields["Fieldname"]

Tags: azure-search

How do I sort my search results using item.Fields["Name"}?

```
var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>();
queryable  = queryable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields["MyDateField"]);
var results = queryable.GetResults();
```

It throws an error when I run it:

> The method 'get_Item' is not supported. Declaring type:
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'x' of type
>   'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem' referenced from
>   scope '', but it is not defined

On the other hand, this works:

```
queryable  = queryable.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
var results = queryable.GetResults();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to define a custom model that inherits from SearchResultItem to define the field you want to sort based upon using the Content Search API.  So assuming your Date field was called `Podcast Date`, you would define the following model:

```
namespace Something.Data
{
   public class PodcastDateSearchItem : SearchResultItem
   {
      [IndexField("podcast_date")]
      public DateTime PodcastDate { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Once you have that, your Content Search Api Query should look like this:

```
namespace Something.Data.Repository
{
    public class AudioRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Items> GetPodcastItems()
        {
            using (var context = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.CreateSearchContext(new SitecoreIndexableItem(Sitecore.Context.Item)))
            {
                var query = context.GetQueryable<PodcastDateSearchItem>();

                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PodcastDate);

                var results = queryable.GetResults();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `Luke` to find out what the index field name is for your field, it's typically all lowercase and spaces are replaced with underscores.

Comment: Absolutely, if it solves your problem, up-vote and mark it the correct answer.  Let me know if you have any other questions.